# How to remove network path from Windows 10 "Devices and Drives"

Tags: windows-10

I use citrix and once I logged into my windows 10 PC, it created a drive option here mapped to my local machine outside citrix. This doesn't work anymore as I disabled permissions. But this option is still showing and throws an error if I open it. How can I remove this option from here?

Error message is:

```
[Window Title]
Network Error

[Main Instruction]
Windows cannot access \\Client\C$

[Content]
You do not have permission to access \\Client\C$. Contact your network administrator to request access.

For more information about permissions, see Windows Help and Support

[Close]
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: In Explorer, right-click this entry and select "Eject" or "Offline". If this didn't help, try the same in Disk Management.

Comment: I right clicked it, but there is no Eject option and also for disk management, it does not show as a drive there, only the C drive shows.

Comment: You could try the following command **diskpart** in PowerShell to see if the disk can be listed.

Comment: It only lists my system name.